# Importing '@metaplex-foundation/js' results in 'process is not defined' error

Tags: metaplex, javascript, typescript, metaplex-js

It looks like [someone previously asked the question and deleted it](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/using-metaplex-js-sdk-with-vitejs-causes-errors-related-to-node-api-calls-not-be) - sadly I can see the question in search engines but can't see the answer!

When I import Metaplex:

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
```

I get the error:

```
client.ts:113 
        
       ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ../node_modules/util/util.js (util.js:109:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=be48f729:18:50)
    at ../node_modules/avsc/lib/utils.js (types.js:11:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=be48f729:18:50)
    at ../node_modules/avsc/lib/types.js (avsc-types.js:17:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=be48f729:18:50)
    at ../node_modules/avsc/etc/browser/avsc-types.js (services.js:11:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=be48f729:18:50)
    at ../node_modules/avsc/etc/browser/avsc-services.js (browser-external:zlib:11:17)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=be48f729:18:50)
```

Uncommenting the import makes the error go away, which is why I'm sure it's Metaplex. I understand the error - it looks like Metaplex wants to use `process` from node. which isn't availabl in the browser - but I can't understand why metaplex wants to use `process` or how to make metaplex not require `process`.

This is a front end project using Svelte and vite.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @ArjunSingh Yes, thanks for the reminder, I've added my solution below for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this adding a polyfill for `process` into my `vite.config.ts`

```
define: {
  "process.env": process.env ?? {},
},
```

Here's my full `vite.config.ts` for reference:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import nodePolyfills from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

// Config is based on metaplex + vite example from:
// https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/getting-started-vite

// es2020 Needed for BigNumbers
// See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/859

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
      events: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events",
      assert: "assert",
      crypto: "crypto-browserify",
      util: "util",
    },
  },
  define: {
    "process.env": process.env ?? {},
  },
  build: {
    target: "es2020",
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [nodePolyfills({ crypto: true })],
    },
    // From https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9703#issuecomment-1216662109
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    // From https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9703#issuecomment-1216662109
    disabled: false,
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      plugins: [NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({ buffer: true })],
      target: "es2020",
    },
  },
});
```